# problem with SimpleXML and inclosed arrays

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I'm having a problem with SIMPLE XML.  I seem to have an array with dumping the whole object.  However, when I try to access the array, I get a single element of the array back.

Here is the full dump:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [@attributes] => Array
        (
            [type] => array
        )

    [person] => Array
        (
            [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                 ..........................
                ),
            [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                 ..........................
                )
        )
)
```

when I try to access the person array through $xml->person, instead of getting the array, I get the first element back.  Any ideas?

Comment: What XML that generates this dump?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [SimpleXML Basic usage](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php) documentation in the PHP Manual:

> **NOTE:** Properties (`$xml->movie` in previous example) are not arrays. They are [iterable](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.iterator.php) and [accessible](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.arrayaccess.php) objects.

So, in your case, `$xml->person` is not actually an array, just an iterable object. It can be easily converted to an array with:

```
$persons = array();
foreach ($xml->person as $person) {
    $persons[] = $person;
}
```